# Is this logic for a profile image uploader be scalable?

Tags: node.js, firebase

Would the following generic logic for implementing a profile upload feature be scalable in production?

```
1. Inside a web app user selects an image to upload
2. Image gets sent to the server where it gets stored in memory and validated using nodejs package called: multer
3. If the image file is valid, a unique name is generated for the file
4. The image is resized to 150 x 150 using nodejs package called: sharp
5. Image is streamed to google cloud storage
6. Once image is saved a public URL of the image is saved under the user’s profile inside of the database
7. The image ULR is sent back to the client and the image gets displayed
```

**Languages used to implement the above**

This would be implemented using:

- firebase cloud functions running on Nodejs as a backend
- Google Cloud Storage for holding images
- firebase database for saving image url for the user uploading the image

**My current concerns with this are:**

- Holding an image in memory while it gets validated and processed will potentially lead to servers clogging up during heavy load
- How would this way of generating a unique name for the image scale?: uuidV4 + current date in milliseconds + last 5 characters of the image's original file name

Comment: Memory-wise you're fine. Serverless is based on the fact that for each request a fresh new instance is created just for that one request. You don't have to worry about the infrastructure - Google can handle those images pretty easily. That being said - if each image has over 100MB, you might run into some performance issues + pretty high costs. For "standard" images, you're fine.

Comment: As for IDs - let Firebase do the work for you. Let it generate IDs - it will handle it.

Comment: Thanks, images would be limited to 2MB and then after being resized to 150x150 would shrunk even lower basically down to kb's

Comment: Then you have nothing to worry about. Be aware of your costs, but don't stress about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) and [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) are efficient enough for your needs:

> Uploaded 2MB pictures downsized to 150x150 resolution.

Let's say you'll have **100,000** users. Every user uploads a picture that gets downsized to **20kb** image. That's **1.907GB ~ 2GB** of storage.

**Google Cloud Storage:**

- One instance in Frankfurt
- 2GB regional storage

> = $0.55 *a year*

**Google Cloud Functions:**

With 100k users, for simplicity, let's assume it will be evenly distributed and so we'll have **8334 per month** users uploading their images. And let's be **extremely** pessimistic and say that one resize function will take **3s**.

- 8334 resize operations per month
- 3s per function
- Networking throughput 2MB per function

> = $16.24 *a year*

So you're good to go. Happy coding!

---

This answer *will* get outdated eventually, so I'm including screenshot of google price calculator:

[image]